# Interactive scatterplot with marginal distributions on the axis R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to create a interactive scatterplot using data from different periods but I want to include marginal distributions on the y axis. For example, it should look like this but with a slider on the bottom so I can select the period that data is drawn from.

```
 library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)

# create sample data for two periods
df1 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100),
  period = rep("Period 1", 100)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100),
  period = rep("Period 2", 100)
)

# combine the data frames
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# create the scatterplot with marginal histograms
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = period)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Scatterplot with Marginal Histograms") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

# add the marginal histograms
marginal_hist <- ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram", margins = 'y', bins = 20)
```

This outputs:
[image]

I would like to have instead a slider at the bottom that could be used to select the data from specific periods. Something like the graph below but with the marginal histograms:

[image]

I tried this:

```
    # create the scatterplot with marginal histograms
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, frame = period)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Scatterplot with Marginal Histograms") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

# add the marginal histograms
marginal_hist <- ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram", bins = 20, margins = "both")

ggplotly(marginal_hist)
```

but it does not work.

Thank you very much for your help!